# ipython notebook capture variables from exception stack trace and prevent me to simply release them

Tags: garbage-collection, jupyter, ipython

When I debug on functions that accepts arguments with large memory usage, I found

```py
#cell [1]:
def error_function(x):
    raise ValueError

import numpy as np
x = np.empty(int(1e10))
x[:] = 0.
error_function(x)  # so throw a ValueError 

#cell [2]:
x = None           # cannot release memory used from x.
```

I can release the out-of-scope variable by clean the exception stack trace and then call `gc.collect()`:

```py
#cell [3]:
raise ValueError           # clean the exception stack trace
  
#cell [4]:
import gc; gc.collect();   # now the out-of-scoped x is released.
```

thats too annoying if I would like to focus on debugging the `error_function` in `cell [1]` (directly re-run `cell [1]` I expect the old `x` will be GCed by `x = np.empty...`)

Is there some better way to deal with this case?